# How to set DNS to work with VPS email server

Tags: dns, email, vps

I have a VPS in one provider (Provider A), and I have set the email server all works ok. in another provider (Provider B) I have the domain registered. So, let's assume it is mydomain.com

**On the provider B:**
I had created a subdomain called mail.mydomain.com, configured the dns as follow:

```
HOST         Type    Result
(empty)      A       123.123.123.123
www          A       123.123.123.123
mail         A       123.123.123.123
```

Then on mail exchange records I've configured as follow:

```
HOST            Priority   Result
(empty)         30         123.123.123.123
```

On the subdomain mail.mydomain.com, I have configured the dns as follow:

```
HOST         Type    Result
(empty)      A       123.123.123.123
www          A       123.123.123.123
```

Comment: An A record on `mail.mydomain.com` set to your IP, a MX record on `mydomain.com` set to `mail.mydomain.com` and you probably also wanna set up two TXT records: DKIM and SPF…

Comment: ok I will try but, so I don't need pop.mydomain.com, or smtp.mydomain.com? then on gmail for example, should I just use always mail.mydomain.com independently of the protocol?

Comment: ok tried all that, did dig +short mail.mydomain.com, ip is correct, but telnet on ports 587, 465, 25 none of them connects..

Comment: Yep, just `mail.mydomain.com` for SMTP, IMAP and POP. Have you actually set up your mail server and opened that ports on a firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set up your mail server(s) to listen at `mail.mydomain.com`
2. Make sure your firewall doesn't block your mail server(s)'s ports
3. Set an A record on `mail.mydomain.com` pointing to your IP address
4. Set a MX record on `mydomain.com` pointing to `mail.mydomain.com`
5. It should be working, but you probably wanna set up [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail), [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) and [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)

Comment: it does not fix my issue, but it is certain the way DNS should be set.

Comment: @sudo.ie: So, what's your issue?

Comment: all seems ok, but it still not work, so dns seems to point ok, mail server looks ok, firewall lookgs ok, but when I try to connect to mail.mydomain.com on any email port, it does not connect.